# How to use an array with prisma upsert in transaction

Tags: javascript, express, prisma

I'm trying to pass an array in my request. My array can have up to 6 entries, but how to use them all with upsert using Prisma ?

The models used :

```
model Board {
  id      String   @id @unique @default(uuid())
  title   String
  User    User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId  Int
  columns Column[]
  tasks   Task[]
}

model Column {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  column  String
  Board   Board  @relation(fields: [boardId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  boardId String
  tasks   Task[]
}
```

The function :

```
    const columns = req.body.columns;
    
    const updateBoardData = prisma.board.update({
      where: { id: req.body.id },
      data: { title: req.body.title },
    });

    const upsertColumns = prisma.column.upsert({
      where: { id: 65 }, //If id exists, it's updated
      update: columns[0],
      create: columns[0],
    });

    await prisma
      .$transaction([updateBoardData, upsertColumns])
      .then((board) => {
        return res.status(201).json({ board });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json(`${err}`);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        return prisma.$disconnect();
      });
```

The problem with this function is, if the id exists,the update is done on the right column (the table i want to apply the update or create), but if the id doesn't exist, i am having this following error :

```
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.board.update()` invocation in
C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Kanban\Server\src\routes\boards\boards.controllers.js:170:42

  167 const columns = req.body.columns;
  168 const boardId = req.body.id;
  169
→ 170 const updateBoardData = prisma.board.update(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `PRIMARY`
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Kanban\Server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34310:13)
    at RequestHandler.request (C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Kanban\Server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34293:12)
    at async PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Kanban\Server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35273:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async updateBoard (C:\Users\Sébastien\Desktop\Kanban\Server\src\routes\boards\boards.controllers.js:189:5) {
  code: 'P2002',
  clientVersion: '4.6.0',
  meta: { target: 'PRIMARY' }
}
```

The request sent via postman is the following one :

```
{ 
    "id": "fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc",
    "title": "TITLE UPDATED",
    "columns": [
        { "id": 65, "column": "TODO", "boardId": "fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc"}, 
        { "id":66, "column": "DONE", "boardId": "fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc"}, 
        { "column": "NEW COLUMN", "boardId": "fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc" }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE : Console.log(req.body)

```
{
  id: 'fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc',
  title: 'TITLE UPDATED',
  columns: [
    {
      id: 65,
      column: 'TODO',
      boardId: 'fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc'
    },
    {
      id: 66,
      column: 'DONE',
      boardId: 'fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc'
    },
    {
      column: 'NEW COLUMN',
      boardId: 'fe6e843a-bcab-4404-85d0-8324794f04cc'
    }
  ]
}
```

So my two issues are, how to make update and create working together ? And how make it dynamically while using every entries of the columns array.

Comment: When you say the `id` exist it work else it doesn't, are you talking about the board id or the column id?

Comment: I'm talking about the columnId

Comment: Did you log your req.body ?

Comment: I've just added the console.log of req.body in the post

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: It's a mysql database, named kanban

Comment: The error suggests that your first update function is failing, which is strange because you are just updating a title, was there a unique constraint on title field before?